# Error while I try to add a product in Spreecommerce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I installed the internationalization extension and the taxes extension on my spree commerce 2.0, but, now I'm trying to add a new product, and this message is displayed:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in
>   Spree::Admin::PropertiesController#create
>
> Could not find table 'spree_property_translations'

I executed this command: `rake db:migrate` but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spree_property_translations table is not provided by Spree, or any extension that I know of.  If this is coming from an extension you can run:

```
rake railties:install:migrations
rake db:migrate
```

to copy migrations from the gem to your project.

Most extensions support an installer script which will install and run the migrations, and install required CSS/JS:

```
rails g EXTENSION_NAME:install
```